# iOS Facebook SDK lost session constantly

Tags: ios, token

Last time users of our app started complain that each day they see login screen and they need to login to Facebook back again, which never happened before. Our investigation shows that iOS SDK lose access token after short period of time, `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is nil.

Facebook SDK version: 16.2.1
Platform: iOS

Our users massively started complaining about issue since 25 Dec 2023. Does anyone faced this problem?